# Serialize and deserialize a tree

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree, serialization

Suppose each node of a tree has maximum `n` children. I want to serialize and de-serialize for a tree. My current solution is doing pre-order traverse, and using `#` to represent `None` child.

I'm wondering if there are any better implementation method. My current concern for my code is if the tree has too many `None` node (kinds of sparse tree), there will be a lot `#` in the serialized string output. But I have not figured out a way to represent serialized tree better, since I think for `None` node, we still need some kinds of information to represent there is an empty node there.

I'm looking forward to any smart ideas on existing code and smart ideas to represent serialized tree in a better (more compact and more efficient -- for both serialize and de-serialize).

My print tree method is just for the purpose of verification. `deserialize` is correctly re-constructing the tree, so we can skip code review for this part.

```
number_of_children = 3
index = 0
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = [] # a list of Node

    def serialize(self, result): # serialzie a tree into a string
        result.append(str(self.value))
        for child in self.children:
            if child:
                child.serialize(result)
            else:
                result.append('#')

    def printTree(self): # print tree layer by layer
        current_level_buffer=[]
        current_level_buffer.append(self)
        current_level_count = 1
        next_level_count=0
        next_level_buffer=[]
        print_buffer=[]
        next_level_valid = 1
        while True:
            node = current_level_buffer.pop(0)
            if not node:
                print_buffer.append('#')
                current_level_count -= 1
            else:
                print_buffer.append(str(node.value))
                current_level_count -= 1
                for child in node.children:
                    next_level_buffer.append(child)
                    next_level_count += 1
                    if child:
                        next_level_valid += 1
            if current_level_count == 0:
                print ' '.join(print_buffer)
                current_level_count = next_level_count
                current_level_buffer = next_level_buffer
                next_level_count = 0
                next_level_buffer=[]
                print_buffer=[]
                if next_level_valid == 0:
                    return
                next_level_valid = 0


def deserialize(source):  # deserialize a string into a tree
    global index
    current_node = None
    if source[index] != '#':
        current_node = Node(source[index])
        for i in range(number_of_children):
            index += 1
            current_node.children.append(deserialize(source))
    return current_node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node(0)
    child11 = Node(1)
    child12 = Node(2)
    root.children.append(child11)
    root.children.append(child12)
    root.children.append(None)
    child21 = Node(3)
    child22 = Node(4)
    child23 = Node(5)
    child11.children.append(child21)
    child11.children.append(child22)
    child11.children.append(child23)
    child24=Node(6)
    child25=Node(7)
    child26=Node(8)
    child12.children.append(child24)
    child12.children.append(child25)
    child12.children.append(child26)

    leafnodes = [child21, child22, child23, child24, child25, child26]
    for leaf in leafnodes:
        leaf.children.append(None)
        leaf.children.append(None)
        leaf.children.append(None)

    root.printTree()
    result = []
    root.serialize(result)
    print result
    print ''.join(result)

    new_root = deserialize(''.join(result))
    new_root.printTree()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `printTree` function is unnecessarily long.

Also, I really don't like the output of your `serialize`. I was not able to parse (as a human) this back into the structure of the tree. For me it would be much better if the structure was apparent from the serialization.

Therefore I rewrote your code in the following way:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value='#', children=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children if children else []

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.value != '#'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value and self.children == other.children

    def __str__(self):
        buf, out = [self], []
        while buf:
            # current level
            out.append(", ".join(str(node.value) for node in buf))
            if any(node for node in buf):
                # add children
                buf = [subnode if subnode else Node()
                       for node in buf
                       for subnode in node.children]
            else:
                break
        return "\n".join(out)

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self:
            return "Node()"
        children_repr = ",".join(repr(child) for child in self.children)
        return "Node({.value},[{}])".format(self, children_repr)

    def serialize(self):
        return repr(self).replace("Node", "").replace("()", "#")

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(source):
        return eval(source.replace("#", "()").replace("(", "Node("))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node(1, [Node(2, [Node(4)]), Node(3, [Node(5), Node(6)])])
    print repr(root)
    print root
    source = root.serialize()
    root2 = Node.deserialize(source)
    print repr(root2)
    print root2
    assert root == root2
```

This class has the nice feature, that `eval(repr(root))` is a copy of `root`, so `repr(root)` is a serialization of `root`.

The output of `repr(root)` is a bit verbose, though:

```
Node(1,[Node(2,[Node(4,[])]),Node(3,[Node(5,[]),Node(6,[])])])
```

Therefore I defined a `serialize` function, which just gets rid of all the `Node`s. The deserialize function just puts them back in and does an `eval`.

Note that I used a different tree here than you. Here would be your structure:

```
root = Node(0, [Node(1, [Node(3, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(4, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(5, [Node(), Node(), Node()])]),
                Node(2, [Node(6, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(7, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(8, [Node(), Node(), Node()])]),
                Node()])
```

Or, even better to visualize:

```
root = Node(0, [Node(1, [Node(3, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()]),
                         Node(4, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()]),
                         Node(5, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()])]),
                Node(2, [Node(6, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()]),
                         Node(7, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()]),
                         Node(8, [Node(),
                                  Node(),
                                  Node()])]),
                Node()])
```

Example:

```
>>> root.serialize()
'(0,[(1,[(3,[#,#,#]),(4,[#,#,#]),(5,[#,#,#])]),(2,[(6,[#,#,#]),(7,[#,#,#]),(8,[#,#,#])]),#])'
```

This could be cut down even further, but at this point it becomes a balance between the processing time needed to make this string smaller and the gain in memory from that.

With this function it could become:

```
def serialize2(self):
    replacements = [("Node", ""), ("()", "#"),
                    ("(", ""), (")", ""), (",[", "["), (",", "")]
    out = repr(self)
    for replacement in replacements:
        out = out.replace(*replacement)
    return out

>>> root.serialize2()
'0[1[3[###]4[###]5[###]]2[6[###]7[###]8[###]]#]'
```

But this becomes hard to parse back into the tree and would break the setup of using `__repr__` and `eval`. It would be possible using some fancy regular expressions, though.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, love your code and your comments. Wondering if you have any better ideas to represent the tree serialization form? Our implementation is similar, which is using `#` to represent empty child, and when there are large number of empty child, we end with a lot of `#` -- e.g. the tree is not kinds (or far from) of full tree.

Comment: BTW, dumb question, what is the benefit of using `repr ` in this problem, comparing using a more general method like serialization?

Comment: @LinMa Yeah, I was thinking of that. It would be sufficient for my code to have `()` represent a completely empty node. It makes the repr function slightly more complicated, but it might be worth it.

Comment: @LinMa In my opinion __repr__ is a lot more general than a specialized serialize. Which is why the latter is just a special case of the former in my code.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, could you elaborate a bit more why you think `repr` is better general? From the name, hard to think it is for serialization.

Comment: I do not quite understand why using `()` is more compact? `()` are two chars, but `#` is only one char, latter is more compact?

Comment: @LinMa It is for representation (i.e.representing the total structure of the object). Ideally it is represented in such a way that `eval(repr(object))` works, which it is here.

Comment: @LinMa In this version of my code, the empty node is still `Node('#', [])` in `repr`, while `Node()` would be enough. Working on a streamlining of this, where the serialized string is less than half the length of this one.

Comment: Thanks Graipher for the patience to explain, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: BTW, a bit lost by this line of code `"Node({.value},[{}])".format(self, children_repr)`, wondering how `.value` is replaced by real value?

Comment: BTW, Graipher, another confusion is for your code `subnode if subnode else Node() for node in buf for subnode in node.children`, which is inner, and which is outer loop? A bit lost here.

Comment: @LinMa `str.format` can do a limited number of operations, namely attribute access and indexing: `x = [1, 2, 3]; "{0[1]}".format(x); "{[1]}".format(x); "{x[1]}".format(x=x)` all return `2`. Similarly my code prints `self.value` with `"{.value}".format(self)`.

Comment: @Yeah, that always confuses me as well and I have to look it up. It is just like if you wrote it as actual for loops, the later `for`(s) are the inner one(s).

Comment: Thanks for the patience of explaining to me, love your code style of elegancy, vote up for your reply, have a good day Graipher.

Comment: Hi Graipher, your code output format is like, `Node(1,[Node(2,[Node(4,[])]),Node(3,[Node(5,[]),Node(6,[])])])` -- which is a one line output, how do you visualize into multi-line format? Multi-line format is like below, in your 2nd example,

Comment: root = Node(0, [Node(1, [Node(3, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(4, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(5, [Node(), Node(), Node()])]),
                Node(2, [Node(6, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(7, [Node(), Node(), Node()]),
                         Node(8, [Node(), Node(), Node()])]),
                Node()])

Comment: @LinMa I added those manually. `print root` gives you at least output separated by depth, but without the nesting.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, vote up. Wondering any thoughts to print with nesting?